# "Whatever the truth is, we won't change our minds" or " Whatever the truth, we won't change our minds", which is correct?

Tags: grammar

- *Whatever the truth is, we won't change our minds*

or

- *Whatever the truth, we won't change our minds.*

I saw a sentence like the latter, and I found the same usage in Cambridge Dictionary. I am not sure about what the difference is here, and how to grammatically analyze sentences like the latter.

Comment: Have you done any kind of research for this, Ben? I suggest you look up _ellipsis_.

Comment: Unnuanced multiple-guess questions like “Which one is correct?” that neither present nor solicit evidence, theories, research, or references are off-topic proofreading requests of little lasting value to future site visitors.

Comment: [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cost) gives 'He's determined to win, whatever the cost.' There is a deleted form of 'be' (perhaps with a modal) here, an example of _be-deletion_.

Comment: Why do you think that one of those is "correct" and that the other of those is "incorrect"?